# How to identify a coax connector vs twisted pair connector

Tags: voltage, current, differential, coax, twisted-pair

I need to have a connector that will bring in COAX input to my PCB.

I have this [Rosenberger](https://www.rosenberger.com/0_documents/de/catalogs/ba_automotive/AUTO_HSD_Catalog_2017.pdf) HSD Connector Catalog.

On page 33, "99S12D-40MA5-y" - is this connector a twisted pair connector or Rosenberger connector?

I am not sure that it is a Coax connector. Can someone please clarify which are the coax connectors in the catalog.

Comment: Perhaps you might consider looking over [these](https://www.digikey.com/en/product-highlight/a/amphenol-sv-microwave/rf-coaxial-pcb-connectors) or [these](https://www.mouser.com/new/amphenol/amphenol-coaxial-pcb-connectors/) or [these](https://www.amphenol.com/node/3630) to see what they generally look like. They generally do not include four signal pins.

Comment: Thank you. But is 99S12D-40MA5-y Coax connector or Twisted pair connector?

Comment: What type of coax?  Part number, RG designation, impedance, diameter - anything?  That part number looks like some kind of shielded connector, but automotive parts are weird.

Comment: It's probably a quadraxial. The two shields are concentric and there is also a twisted pair (maybe two in this case given the four signal wire spec.) I would NOT call it coax. But I might be convinced to consider it twisted pairs.

Comment: If you just need coax, why not use BNC or SMA or something else cheap and common?

Comment: The 99S12D-40MA5-y has 4 signal and 2 power pins. So, it is like having power and signal through a single connector to make the design compact instead of having separate connectors. But I am confused whether to take this connector as COAX or Twisted pair?

Comment: So, the above connector is COAX or twisted pair?

Comment: It is not a coax connector.  It is apparently intended to be used with twisted pair cable.

Comment: Thank you. So, I will look for some other connector that will accept coax and power